# Caching huge data into the disk

Tags: c#, database, caching, synchronization

I have a requirement where huge amount of data needs to be cached on the disk.
Whenever there is a change in the database, the data is retreived from the database and cached on the disk. I will be having a background process which keeps checking my cached data with the data base, and updates it as and when required.

I would like to know what would be the best way to organize the cached data on my disk, so that writing and reading from the cache can be faster.
An another thread would be used to fetch some new data from the db and cache it on the disk. I also need to take care of synchronization between the two threads.(one will be updating the existing cache data, and the other will be writing newly fetched data into the cache.)
Please suggest a strategy for organizing the data on the cache and also synchronization between the threads.

Comment: This is crazy. Caching on the disc?? Did you mean `archiving` on the disk? Database already has built-in caching - and is ever more efficient and intelligent than whatever hand-made storage someone comes up with.

Comment: Yes, I will caching on the hard disk. This is to avoid multiple database calls and transfer of data from the database server.

Comment: That is not caching. That is `archiving`. Caching is meant to speed things by storing on **more volatile storage**. That is not what you are doing.

Comment: You should look at replication or mirroring.

Comment: I would say this definitely *is* caching, as it distributes request processing load away from the database to satellite servers. In fact this is the basis of memcachedb!

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has something called XML tables. Those tables are based on physical XML files located in the disk. You can map/link XML data in the disk to a table in SQL Server. For users, it is seamless, in other words they see those tables as a regular tables.

Besides technical/philosophical discussion about caching huge data on the disk, this is just an idea...

Answer (score 1):

Do you care about the consistancy of the data? on power failures?

Memory mapped files along with occational flushes porbably get want you want

Do you need to have an indexed access to data?

You probably need to design something B-tree implementation or B+tree implementation. which gives efficient retrival of the indexed data and better block level locking.

http://code.google.com/p/high-concurrency-btree/

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative answer, my own [B+Tree implementation](http://csharptest.net/projects/bplustree/) will neatly address this as a completely managed code (C#) implementation of an IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.  It is a single-file key/value store that is thread-safe and optimized for concurrency.  It was built from the ground up expressly for this purpose and for providing write-through caches.

- Dicussion - http://csharptest.net/projects/bplustree/
- Online Help – http://help.csharptest.net/
- Source Code – http://code.google.com/p/csharptest-net/
- Downloads – http://code.google.com/p/csharptest-net/downloads
- NuGet Package – http://nuget.org/List/Packages/CSharpTest.Net.BPlusTree